# Cannot read property 'Vector'/'Draw' of undefined in React JS

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am trying to draw some rectangular shape in map using react js with open layer. But,I am getting an error as "Cannot read property 'Vector' of undefined" /"Cannot read property 'Draw' of undefined".

I am getting an error after importing all the necessary class. See the code which is available in between two comments.

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import 'ol/ol.css';
import ol from 'ol';
import Map from 'ol/map';
import View from 'ol/view';
import Tile from 'ol/layer/tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/osm';
import proj from 'ol/proj';
import Vector from 'ol/source/vector';
import Draw from 'ol/interaction/draw';

class MapComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    var map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new Tile({
          source: new OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 4
      })
    })

  //To draw Rectangle in Map - Begins
    var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});
    var geometryFunction = ol.interaction.Draw.createRegularPolygon(4);

    var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: 'Square',
      geometryFunction: geometryFunction
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
 //To draw Rectangle in Map - Ends
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div id="map"></div>

    )
  }
}

export default MapComponent;
```

**Screenshot:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing Vector and Draw but using ol.source.Vector to use them.

Instead replace:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});
```

With:

```
var source = new Vector({wrapX: false});
```

Similarly for Draw.

Comment: Thanks!! . Now I am able to draw the shape. But the shape is not getting displayed after the double click

Comment: I think the answer to your original question is as mentioned above. Can you provide more context on your follow up question please?

Comment: I will raise it as separate question for the followup question.